# Как написать обобщенный запрос hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Как написать обобщенный метод

```
public T getEntity(long id) {
    return null;
}
```

который возвращает сущность по ее `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запросы в `Hibernate` можно написать несколькими разными способами:

- с использованием `criteria api`:

  ```
  List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
       .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Iz%") )
       .add( Restrictions.gt( "weight", new Float(minWeight) ) )
       .addOrder( Order.asc("age") )
       .list();
  ```
- с использованием `HQL`:

  ```
  String hql = "FROM Cat";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  List results = query.list();
  ```

Ссылки на документацию: [hql](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) и [criteria api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)

Чтобы параметризировать метод DAO вижу несколько вариантов:

1. явно передавать объект типа `Class<T>`

   ```
   public T getEntity(long id, Class<T>type)
   ```
2. Создать абстрактный класс с generic методами и для каждой сущности создать отдельный класс DAO. Например,

   ```
   public class Cat extends AbstractDao<Cat>
   ```

Чтобы получить объект типа `Class<T>` из класса родителя можно явно в конструкторе класса `Cat` его передать.

```
public Cat(){
    super(Cat.class);
}
```

Либо, есть более элегантное решение - определить класс `AbstractDao` следующим образом:

```
public class AbstractDao<T>{
   private final Class<T> type;

   protected AbstractDao(){
       ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.type = (Class<T>) superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: как написать метод для конкретной сущности я знаю. Не понятно как быть если вместо Cat обобщенная сущность T?

Comment: никак, вам нужен объект типа Class<?> чтобы написать criteria. Обычно это делается при помощи наследования. Создается некоторый абстрактный класс с использованием generics, а потом этот класс уже наследуется с нужным типом. например есть AbstractDAO<T>, тогда CatDao extends Abstract<Cat>. Пример - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/2196511. Либо объект Class<T> вам нужно явно передавать в каждый метод.